# Create package.json from package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, webpack, package.json, package-lock.json

I downloaded a theme and it has a package-lock.json file but no package.json file.
Is there a way I can generate the package.json from the package-lock.json file.
How do I install the node modules with just the package-lock.json file.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install`?

Comment: I have but it gives me no package.json file found

Comment: Something not right with the theme because package.json is necessary to install other dependencies.. what’s the url of the theme ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858814/npm-to-create-a-package-json-file-out-of-the-package-lock-json-file

Answer (score 42):

###### Warning: Do not attempt before reading comments below & backup package-lock.json.

---

Install the latest npm with `npm install -g npm`

Run `npm init` and respond to the questions.

The above command will generate a `package.json` and include the existing packages listed in `package-lock.json`

Comment: I tried it with the latest npm (`6.4.1`) and it doesn't work. It only creates a `package.json` file without any dependencies listed.

Comment: @Amade Interesting I was able to recover my packages with that command :/

Comment: @MajAfy Well, I'm not sure why (shrug)

Comment: npm `6.6.0`. `package.json` does not include the existing packages listed in `package-lock.json`

Comment: 6.9.0 and it is still not working, neither is npm ci - what is the point of this file's use in CI if it seems to be ignored ?

Comment: Worked for me with version 6.4.1

Comment: see @paul 's answer below

Comment: wiped out package-lock.json

Comment: This wiped out my package-json. I've edited the question with a warning but I'm not knowledgeable enough about this to know what's going on or if it's just not possible.

Answer (score 28):

I think I figured it out.

I don't think `npm init` can draw from package-lock.json. However it **does** seem to pull from what is already in your **/node_modules**. I believe this is why @Harry B's solution works for some and not at all for others.

For example, if you have just cloned your project which contains package-lock.json, no package.json, and empty/non-existence node_modules, `npm init` won't create any dependencies.  However, if you run `npm install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 ...` *then* run `npm init` it *will* create the dependencies in package.json.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation. I cloned a project to local that included node_modules but not package.json, so I couldn't rebuild and deploy. This was the perfect solution to my issue.

Comment: This is perfect comment on situation, but it has nothing to do with answering to the question: `How do I install the node modules with just the package-lock.json file`

Answer (score 20):

https://pravnyadv.github.io/unpackage/ seems to work.  Copy your package lock file text in, hit the button, copy out the text into a new package.json file.

Comment: That's the perfect solution

Comment: This should be selected as the valid answer.

Comment: https://pravnyadv.github.io/unpackage/ may return your `package.json` a single line.


If so and you'd like to unfurl it a multi-line format, pipe it into `jq` with:
`echo '$your_package_blobl' | jq`

Comment: I am late here, but the above link: https://pravnyadv.github.io/unpackage/ is not working anymore, do you have any alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

**package-lock.json** file relies on the presence of a **package.json** file, So it's not possible to retrieve **package.json** (happy to be proved wrong).

So a possible solution left is to use a module like [auto-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-install) which is capable of generating **package.json** from the project file dependencies.

First, you need to install the module globally `npm install -g auto-install`. Then run `npm init` and answer the basic requirements.

Then, run `auto-install` in your project root directory. All the dependencies should reflect in **package.json** file.

**

### Or Install node modules directly from package-lock.json

**

Run `npm ci` which bypasses a package’s package.json to install modules from a package’s lockfile.

[More Information](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable)

Comment: `npm ci` always tells me "added 0 packages" and `auto-install` **rewrote my _package-lock.json_**, installed 2 random packages and stopped at "Watchers initialized"... _node_modules_ folder was created but only with these 2 packages... Glad I had a lock backup :(

Comment: `npm ci` **depends** on `package.json` so it cannot be used with only `package-lock.json` present

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a very old question, but all of these answers are sooo close to solving the problem, yet none of them worked for me because my node_modules folder was empty.  they did however lead me to an answer, which is basically a combination of the previous suggestions.

##### preliminary boilerplate:

before doing anything, make a backup of your package-lock.json, just in case, and run `npm install -g npm` just in case you're wildly out of date, although this may not be necessary...  i am using npm 8.19.4 because that's what it happens to be for me.

##### first:

run `npm ci`

this will generate the node_modules that you need, but then it will complain about a missing `package.json` and appear to fail.  don't worry, that's fine.

##### second:

run `npm init` and answer all the questions, you can literally just hit enter to each one because whatever.

this will create your `package.json`, and now it should be fully populated with the node_modules that were generated by the first step.

##### third:

profit!