# npm to create a package.json file out of the package-lock.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've got a project which happens to have a full node_modules directory, and a `package-lock.json` file, but no `package.json` file.

so I ran `npm init` to create a new `package.json` file, but now I'm struggling to make it contain the dependecies of the project.

Is there a way to make npm read the node_modules directory or the `package-lock.json` and create a matching `package.json` file?

Comment: what happens when you run npm update

Comment: it doesnt change anything in the packagejson file :(

Comment: maybe parsing JS files to find out all `require` and `import` would help. it will not work say for webpack or babel's plugins but at least for application code it should

Comment: sounds interesting. ill try that out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create package.json from package-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038891/create-package-json-from-package-lock-json)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `package-lock.json` does not contain enough information to produce an accurate `package.json` file. It contains a list of all the package that are installed, and the version, but it also includes sub-dependencies in the list.

You could read the information and create a new dependencies list, but you would end up with a list of all the dependencies, including sub-dependencies you don't directly depend on. There would also be no distinction between `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

Interestingly, npm does seem to be able to remember which packages were installed in a given directory for some amount of time (it's probably cached somewhere). If the lock file was originally created on your machine, a simple `npm init` *might* give you an accurate `package.json` file.

If you really want to produce a list of all the packages in a JSON format, you could use a script like this:

```
var dependencies = require('./package-lock.json').dependencies;
var list = {};

for (var p of Object.keys(dependencies)) {
    list[p] = dependencies[p].version;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, '  '));
```

Comment: you are right, there is no official command to produce such a thing, but i need a packagejson file desperatly. do you have any idea for a workaround, such as a script that will list the dependecies for me?

Comment: @Efrat I added a little script that can list out the dependencies.

Comment: I don't know what I did. I ran this as "node package-list.js". It worked great! I +1'd the answer. Then, I upgraded npm to 6.14.5.
I deleted the incomplete package.json in this project that had only a package-lock.json before I attempted `npm init`. So, that deleted I ran `npm init` again, accepted all the defaults, and my package.json has like 184 packages in "dependencies" now!? Sweird. I've not look at release notes, but maybe this was just introduced?