# How to make package.json from package-lock.json file

Tags: node.js, npm

I am learning backend side using node.js and express framework.
I added modules by `npm install *** --save`.
After several hours i noticed that my project didn't contain package.json file.

There's only package-lock.json

I am now trying to add test command to use nodemon.
Like `dev: nodemon app.js`.
but there's no such part in package-lock.json file.

I don't want to start from scratch again.

Comment: run `npm init` and answer the questions to create a package.json

Comment: will it contain all dependencies i have already installed? @Roland Starke

Comment: @ChrisM hi, it's the the question i'm asking.

Comment: @DanKonus Yes, `npm init` will add the already installed node modules to `package.json`.

Comment: Yey, it works without break. Thanks for your time, guys.

Comment: you can use `npm init -y` to generate it without user prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038891/create-package-json-from-package-lock-json

Answer (score -2):

package-lock.json: records the exact version of each installed package which allows you to re-install them. Future installs will be able to build an identical dependency tree.

package.json: records the minimum version you app needs. If you update the versions of a particular package, the change is not going to be reflected here.